# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap

Tags: collections

I am using Spring-core 3.2 jar but I am getting error as

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap".

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(); 
formData.add("xxx","xxxx");
formData.add("yyy","yyy");                      
formData.add("r","5");
formData.add("d","0");
```

I need to pass this data to HTTP post but I am getting above error. I have imported below Jars:

```
import org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
```

Comment: may be the required jar missing in your class path.

Comment: I have added the below jar.  Spring-core -3.2.6.jar but still getting same response.  find the below error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
 ...

Comment: are you using any IDE ? is this maven project ?

Comment: Yes IDE as Eclipse and Maven project.

Comment: I have a project which uses Spring REST and I only have added spring-web inside my POM. Try the same

Answer (score 0):

try dependency

org.springframework spring-web 5.3.10